# Deleting Rows Leading Up to a Value in R

Tags: r

I have a large time-series data set made up of person-level information beginning in 2014 and ending 2019. The columns of importance related to my question include: ID, Dosage  Date and row_nbr. An example is below:

```
df<-data.frame(ID=rep(1999,66),Dosage=c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,15,15,15,0,0,20,20,20,20,20,0,0,0,0,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,0,0,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,0,0,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35),Date=seq(as.Date('2014-01-01'),length.out=66,by='month'),row_nbr=seq(66))
```

What I would like to do is delete all rows leading up the first row where the dosage is greater than 0.

An example of what I'd like the data to look like when the data is filtered is:

```
df2<-data.frame(ID=rep(1999,46),Dosage=c(15,15,15,0,0,20,20,20,20,20,0,0,0,0,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,0,0,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,0,0,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35),Date=seq(as.Date('2015-09-01'),length.out=46,by='month'),row_nbr=seq(46))
```

I'm not sure how to tackle this problem, I could potentially do this: `df<-df%>%filter(! row_nbr==1 & Dosage==0)` and then recalc the row numbers and rerun the code over and over, but I wanted to see if anyone has an idea of how to better tackle this problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although `grep` will probably work, you might want a direct solution that doesn't involve string conversions:

```
i=first(which(df$Dosage>0))
tail(df, -i+1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the input and your answer. Your answer solved my problem perfectly!

Comment: Can this answer be applicable to a large data set that uses a group_by function? For instance: `df<-group_by(ID)%>%mutate(i=first(which(Dosage>0)))`. If I run this code I get: `Error: Column i must be length 2 (the group size) or one, not 0`

Comment: First, get rid of the "i=" part. I created the variable so it's easier to see what's going on. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

I am not good at Regular expression...so please feel free to correct me :)

```r
non_0_row <- grep("[^0]",df$Dosage)

non_0_row
#>  [1] 21 22 23 26 27 28 29 30 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 48 49 50 51 52 53
#> [26] 54 55 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66

df[-(1:non_0_row[1]),]
#>      ID Dosage       Date row_nbr
#> 22 1999     15 2015-10-01      22
#> 23 1999     15 2015-11-01      23
#> 24 1999      0 2015-12-01      24
#> 25 1999      0 2016-01-01      25
#> 26 1999     20 2016-02-01      26
#> 27 1999     20 2016-03-01      27
#> 28 1999     20 2016-04-01      28
#> 29 1999     20 2016-05-01      29
#> 30 1999     20 2016-06-01      30
#> 31 1999      0 2016-07-01      31
#> 32 1999      0 2016-08-01      32
#> 33 1999      0 2016-09-01      33
#> 34 1999      0 2016-10-01      34
#> 35 1999     10 2016-11-01      35
#> 36 1999     10 2016-12-01      36
#> 37 1999     10 2017-01-01      37
#> 38 1999     10 2017-02-01      38
#> 39 1999     10 2017-03-01      39
#> 40 1999     10 2017-04-01      40
#> 41 1999     10 2017-05-01      41
#> 42 1999     10 2017-06-01      42
#> 43 1999     10 2017-07-01      43
#> 44 1999     10 2017-08-01      44
#> 45 1999     10 2017-09-01      45
#> 46 1999      0 2017-10-01      46
#> 47 1999      0 2017-11-01      47
#> 48 1999     20 2017-12-01      48
#> 49 1999     20 2018-01-01      49
#> 50 1999     20 2018-02-01      50
#> 51 1999     20 2018-03-01      51
#> 52 1999     20 2018-04-01      52
#> 53 1999     20 2018-05-01      53
#> 54 1999     20 2018-06-01      54
#> 55 1999     20 2018-07-01      55
#> 56 1999      0 2018-08-01      56
#> 57 1999      0 2018-09-01      57
#> 58 1999     35 2018-10-01      58
#> 59 1999     35 2018-11-01      59
#> 60 1999     35 2018-12-01      60
#> 61 1999     35 2019-01-01      61
#> 62 1999     35 2019-02-01      62
#> 63 1999     35 2019-03-01      63
#> 64 1999     35 2019-04-01      64
#> 65 1999     35 2019-05-01      65
#> 66 1999     35 2019-06-01      66
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! This does work, but when I apply it to my actual data, for some reason it also deletes the first row where Dosage > 0. I'll have to play around with the code a little, again thank you for your help!